# How do I change the footer (Norma)

Tags: footer

I'm a total novice and this is my first experience with wordpress. I have some basic knowledge of HTML but that's about it. I need to change the the address information that we have set up in the footer. The theme that is being used is "Norma". If additional info is needed, I'll be happy to provide it, just let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually theme provides an option under Appearance/Customize (or around it) to adjust L&F. Because this is a commercial theme I can´t install or test it. You should better ask to their support people.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, that's exactly where I needed to go to edit the info!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have FTP Access it will be a bit harder. If you don't have Admin Access it will be impossible.

**FTP**

WordPress is structured relatively simple. You won't need to make changes in `wp-admin` or `wp-includes` do go into the `wp-content` folder, then `themes` then your currently active theme. Here you'll find a bunch of connected PHP files, be careful because misplacing a bracket or semi-colon could throw your entire website "out-of-wack". You're looking for `footer.php` to edit. Edit it change what you need and upload it.

**Admin Access**

First check to see if your theme comes with some way to edit that sort of thing. Usually there's an extra menu item at the bottom called "Theme Settings", this could be under "Appearance" or "Settings" but if it's there, look through that to see if you're able to change it. Another thing you could do is under "Appearances" there's an "Editor" link which will allow you to edit your theme directly from the admin panel. Again you're looking for `footer.php` to change what you need, then save.

---

If you're not comfortable with editing these PHP files, can't find what you're looking for, and the Theme doesn't come with some kind of built in options to change this sort of things, the safest route would be to spend a $20 and just get a developer to do it for you. Much better option than messing up your theme.

Some helpful links could be:

[Norma Theme Support](http://themeforest.net/item/norma-clean-responsive-wordpress-theme/5372544/support)

[WordPress Theme Support](https://wordpress.org/support/forum/themes-and-templates)

[Getting Started With WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress)

[Stepping Into Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've located that footer.php file, but I'm having trouble finding the line I need to edit.

Comment: @Corey without further information it's hard to say. It's 100% possible that it's being generated by your theme and you're able to edit it from the admin panel ( like the answer below suggests ). If that's the case you'll need to locate it in your Admin Panel as it won't necessarily be obvious in your `footer.php` file ( meaning it wont look like an address but probably a function call ). Maybe submit something to the theme author support or again, worst comes to worst you'll have to shell out a bit of cash for a developer to jump into your theme and change it for you.

Comment: @Corey glad you were able to find a solution, make sure to mark one of the answers correct so future readers know that you've found a solution. Good luck on your WordPress adventures :D !